# XmlDocument sort nodes by the inner text value of a child

Tags: c#, xml, sorting

i want to sort the nodes called ImageInfo by the number in the pos node because i have buttons that change the position up or down and i need to sort the ImageInfo node in the correct order when the pos has changed.

i apologise ahead for not having any c# code but i assure you that i have tried so many different things and im in need of help.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MplAndSiImages xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MplImages>
    <ImageInfo>
      <pos>1</pos>
      <Name>1.png</Name>
      <ParentObjectId>b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8</ParentObjectId>
      <Url>http://localhost:8080/b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8/1.png</Url>
    </ImageInfo>
    <ImageInfo>
      <pos>2</pos>
      <Name>2.png</Name>
      <ParentObjectId>b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8</ParentObjectId>
      <Url>http://localhost:8080/b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8/2.png</Url>
    </ImageInfo>
    <ImageInfo>
      <pos>3</pos>
      <Name>3.png</Name>
      <ParentObjectId>b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8</ParentObjectId>
      <Url>http://localhost:8080/b66a23a8-6268-e611-80e2-c4346bad02e8/3.png</Url>
    </ImageInfo>
  </MplImages>
  <SiImages />
</MplAndSiImages>
```

here is my c# code:

it is called on the click of an action link button and i need it to change the poition to 1 less to move it up in the list and i have the number change but the xml need s to be sorted so it has the ImageInfo nodes in the correct order.

```
public ActionResult MoveUp(string name, string id)
{

    var pathConfig = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductImageFolderPath"];
    var url = pathConfig + id + "\\" + "ModelConfig.xml";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(url);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNode upNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/MplAndSiImages/MplImages/ImageInfo[Name/text() = '" + name + "']/pos");

    string upNodeValue = upNode.InnerText;
    int upNodeInt = Int32.Parse(upNodeValue);
    upNodeInt = upNodeInt - 1;
    var upNodeString = upNodeInt.ToString();
    upNode.InnerText = upNodeString;

    XmlNode downNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/MplAndSiImages/MplImages/ImageInfo/pos[text() = '" + upNodeString + "']");

    string downNodeValue = downNode.InnerText;
    int downNodeInt = Int32.Parse(downNodeValue);
    downNodeInt = downNodeInt + 1;
    var downNodeString = downNodeInt.ToString();
    downNode.InnerText = downNodeString;

    Func<string, int> ParseIntOrDefault = (string input) =>
    {
        int output;
        int.TryParse(input, out output);
        return output;
    };

    var result = doc.SelectNodes("MplAndSiImages/MplImages/*")
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .OrderBy(element => element.SelectSingleNode("pos").InnerText)
        .ToList();


    doc.Save(url);
    return RedirectToAction("UploadAnImage", new { id = id });
}
```

I have seen this and tried it but is there any way of doing this with xmldocument:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlfile);
var orderedtabs = root.Elements("Tab")
                      .OrderBy(xtab => (int)xtab.Element("Order"))
                      .ToArray();
root.RemoveAll();
foreach(XElement tab in orderedtabs)
    root.Add(tab);
root.Save(xmlfile);
```

I am ordering the images to display on a web page.
and when the move up button is pressed the image will be moved up in the list and swap places with the image above it.

Comment: It seems like you have no code and we shall write it all for you. This site is not a coding service. You should spend some effort and try a few things your own

Comment: sorry i havetried many things i just cant find anything that is right for me (everything is sorted by attribute) sorry i didnt say that but i have been searching for hours and im pretty new to anything to do with xml.

Comment: @Purecrafttube - please explain what you are trying to achieve? Ordering the images for what purpose?

Comment: i have done that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using linq to xml you can:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .Descendants("ImageInfo")
                      .OrderBy(element => element.Element("pos")?.Value)
                      .ToList();
```

And in order to order it by the `int` value of it you can:

```
Func<string,int> ParseIntOrDefault = (string input) =>
{
    int output;
    int.TryParse(input, out output);
    return output;
};

var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .Descendants("ImageInfo")
                      .OrderBy(element => ParseIntOrDefault(element.Element("pos")?.Value))
                      .ToList();
```

Using `XmlDocument` to read the xml you can:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("data.xml");

var result = doc.SelectNodes("MplAndSiImages/MplImages/*")
                .Cast<XmlNode>()
                .OrderBy(element => element.SelectSingleNode("pos").InnerText)
                .ToList();
```

*Here too you can use the `ParseIntOrDefault` from above*

Comment: Seems I'm wrong - this site *is* a coding service. Good to know.

Comment: As per the title, OP is using XmlDocument, not XDocument

Comment: do i need to do anything with the result variable (im working on a webapplication)

Comment: im really sorry but how would i use the result is it doc. something,

Comment: i dont know what i need to do to the result variable to make it do anything i am quite area all together